# Dota 2 can't create a build?

Tags: dota-2

I am trying to create a build for Dota 2 where I can put in all the Items, Talent Tree, Ability Upgrades, Description, Item Descriptions, etc.

I have seen that if you go to the Dota 2 website you can make a build.

This is the link: http://www.dota2.com/workshop/builds.

I have seen that you will see a button saying "Create new Build" where you can go and make your own build but I am not seeing that button. All I see is in the middle of the screen "Browse Steam Guides" and some of my current guides which I have copied and edited from Dota 2 (but can't fully edit them, only the items) or somehow made in the past.

How do I fix this problem? I am logged into steam in the Dota 2 website. I have tried to make a build in steam guides but all I see is some text as a guide.

What do I do?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like that website is like a wiki personally tailored for you so you can view things but can't edit them.

The only way I know how to create/edit builds is on the game itself by going to the heroes tab then the guides sub-tab and clicking, 'create' on the bottom left like in the image. (Also if you select one of your builds then instead of copy it'll say edit)
[image]